# Modern SMB/CIFS usage in Linux with support for standby and reconnections

Tags: linux, networking, network-shares, samba, fuse

For years, I've been using CIFS by mounting the shares with `mount -t cifs`. This is what I still tend to use, because it allows me to mount specific shares without having to run a network discovery. Also, it has a good I/O performance.

The problems arise when network connectivity is lost, or when the machine goes to standby/sleep. Regular CIFS mounts can't handle that. When network connectivity is lost, accessing the shares causes whatever process tries to access the files in them to hang, and not even the `kill` command can really help. Worse, unmounting that non-working share is impossible. Sometimes, a hard reset is the only choice. Similar problems happen when waking up a machine (for example, a laptop).

So I looked at the FUSE based solutions like `smbnetfs`. These solve the aforementioned problem, but they do have a critical flaw: They all insist on running a network discovery. You are supposed to pick a mount point where the discovered machines will show up as subdirectories. But this is absolutely *not* what I want. I want to mount specific shares, and *not* run any network discovery. I regularly have to work with shares that are not visible in such a network scan. Also, I have found CIFS discovery scans to be highly unreliable.

Is there a FUSE based solution that allows me to specifically mount a certain share? Ideally it would be a command line like `<tool> //machine/share share-mountpoint <extra commands like specifying a location where to find auth info like username and password>`.

Or is there perhaps something mount-based coming up that I should be aware of?

Comment: I wonder if `autofs` can improve anything.

Comment: Have you tried `gio mount <url>` and how does it work for you? Can't choose mountpoint with that one unfortunately, but it's in predicatable location.